# ElasticSearch - Get first document with distinct field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

I only want to get one document from many that have the same field value. The following documents are indexed:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "position": 1
},
{
    "name": "Ben",
    "position": 1
}
```

When making a search request for the term position equals one, only one of the documents should be returned.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: How "position" is distinct field here? Can you please explain your question bit?

Comment: I updated the question.